# How we can display flash message in express ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

i want to show success flash message in express js ?
But i am getting following error
`"Error: express-session is required. npm i express-session"`,(i installed express-session but still showing error )Where i am wrong ?

Here is my code

```
var express = require("express");
var app     = express();
var path    = require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Router       = require('router');
var api = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('express-flash-notification');


app.post('/addcontact', function(req, res){

   var name =req.body.name;
   var message =req.body.email;
   var phone =req.body.phone;

        var sql= "insert into contactus(name,message) values ('"+name+"',  '"+message+"')";
        con.query(sql,function(err,rows){
                if(err) throw err;
                })
        req.flash('success', 'This is a flash message using the express-flash module.');
        res.render('pages/contact');
});
```

Comment: express session is not initialized `app.use(session())` ... Look at the doc [here](https://github.com/expressjs/session)